# Segmentation fault:core Dumped while using mvscanw function of ncurses in c on ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I am trying to read a input string from keyboard and display it on new window in ncurses.
The string received is passed to function display.
This function has a linklist .
The string is compared with an element of this linklist structure from the top to the end of the list.
if match is found,it prints those particular list elements and If not, it comes out.

Here's the code:

```
void main()
{
 char *str=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
 mvprintw (1,0, "%s","ivrcode:");
 mvscanw(1,8,"%s",str);
 mvprintw (1,8, "%s",str); 
 initscr ();
 cbreak();
 curs_set (2);
 clear();
 display1(str);
 refresh();


}


void display1(char *r)
{ char * status;
int   thisDTMF;
struct linklist * curser=listhead;
int count;
mvprintw (2,0, "%s","vId");
mvprintw (2,10, "%s","msisdn" );
mvprintw (2,25, "%s","ivrCode" );
mvprintw (2,35, "%s","state" );
mvprintw (2,45, "%s","DTMF" );
count = 4;
while(curser!=NULL)
{ status=getState(curser->state);
  thisDTMF=getDTMF(curser->dtmf);
  if(curser->ivrCode==r)
  { mvprintw (count,0,"%d",curser->vId);
  mvprintw (count,10,"%s",curser->msisdn);
  mvprintw (count,25, "%s",curser->ivrCode );
  mvprintw (count,35, "%s",status );
  if(thisDTMF==35||thisDTMF==42)
      mvprintw (count,45, "%c",thisDTMF );
  else
  mvprintw (count,45, "%d",thisDTMF );
  count++;
  }

      curser=curser->next;
}

 }
```

It is taking input string from keyboard and printing as well.
compiling successfully.
But when i hit enter it shows nothing.
Any suggestions?

Comment: don't allocate memory for `char *str;`

Comment: i have not allocated any memory for char * str

Comment: @user2720337 I think he means YOU dont allocate.. i.e you need to allocate

Comment: I think that's what @Grijesh is trying to say - you *need* to allocate memory for `str`.

Comment: Please `indent` your code before posting it. And learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: sorry,ok i will do that from nowonwwrds.

Comment: Use `gcc -Wall -g` to compile the code. Improve it till you get no warnings. Learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: @Karthik T But i didnt  allocate memory for *Str and it worked well when passed to some other function. then why not here?

Answer (score 2):

```
void main()
{
   char *str; <--- Declaration
   mvprintw (1,0, "%s","ivrcode:");
   mvscanw(1,8,"%s",str);
   mvprintw (1,8, "%s",str); <--- Used without initialzation
   ...
 }
```

Here you are declaring the pointer `str` but you dont initialize it or assign it any value. Then you already use it, so it's undefined behaviour. If you say `it worked well` then that's what undefined behaviour is. It can seemingly work, it can crash, produce wrong output, whatever...

What would you expect to be the output of print if you don't assign it properly?

Comment: but it is not printing from linklist though i have entered the string which is there in linklist so curser->ivrCode should match with string and print.

Comment: Since you didn't post the relevant code, nobody can say what it should or should not do. If you have a provblem with some code you should post an SSCE, otherwise you miss parts which you may consider irrelvant but are not.